# why Decode method in swift4 gives object nil if there is one tag in json payload has type mismatch

Tags: ios, swift

I've json payload as below

```
{
    "name": "Dog",
    "type": 1
}
```

and the class which I want to convert from json to custom type is as below

```
class Animal: Codable {
      var name: String?
      var type: String?
}
```

Decoding process:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var animal: Animal?

        do {
            animal = try decoder.decode(Animal.self, from: data)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {

        } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {

        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
            print("mismatch")
        }
        catch {
            print("some error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        print(animal?.name ?? "Decode did not happen!")
```

Animal object is nil. However as per apple WWDC talk(https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/) it supposed to assign value to nil for type property. Since there is a mismatch in "type" data. (Expected String but Int has been found)

Can you guess what is the reason behind this. If any one of the tag data type is mismatched then whole object is becoming nil doesn't sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message carefully, the reason is very clear (no need to *guess*)

> Expected String but Int has been found

means the (found) value is `Int` but you declared a `String` property

**All** strings in JSON are wrapped in double quotes, the type for `type` is `Int`

```
class Animal: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var type: Int?
}
```

If the JSON contains always both values declare the properties as non-optional by removing the question marks.

The implicit decoder / initializer fails if **any** error occurs, you can see this just from the code syntax. If you want to have finer control write your own custom initializer.

Comment: I think they're aware of that.  They're asking why the type mismatch causes the whole decode to fail instead of just making type nil.

Comment: My question is what dan explained ..not why type is nil .. the whole decode is failing and eventually object is also nil

Comment: In wwdc video as mentioned above they mentioned only that particular property will become nil if there is any error and they particularly said that if we have optional types in class or struct it will set that property value nil not the whole object

Comment: How did it work in wwdc video .. .. is it something am doing wrong ?

Comment: @Leela Optional properties are set to `nil` if they are missing (AKA key not found or value not found), not if there is a type mismatch. If an error occurs then it will be thrown and the initializer will be bailed out of.

Comment: The WWDC video does **not** show a successful decoding in case of a type mismatch.

Comment: Okay .. so we only have to do custom decoding in this case because I am not sure that datatype in payload may mismatch with class property type and I don’t want decoding fail only coz of one tag data type is mismatched ?

Comment: @Leela exactly.

Comment: Blame the owner of the web service for sending inconsistent data ;-)

Comment: @ItaiFerber comment makes sense as well . If there is key, value not found that particular property is set to nil not whole object . I couldn’t upvote his answer 

Comment: @vadian hahaha 

Comment: In case of a *missing* key and optional properties **no error** occurs and the decoding basically succeeds. That's a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

To get `nil` **only for type mismatched property**:

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)) ?? nil
    type = (try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)) ?? nil
}
```